# css drop down according height not auto

Tags: html, css

Hi this dropdown has a set size in the tab-content. It is cut off if its larger than a certain length text. I need it to be auto so that the box adjusts to the size. I tried working the css but no luck, thanks.

```css
.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blue label {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}


/* :checked */

input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 10em;
}


/* Icon */

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-one" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab-one">Label One</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.em ipsum dolor sit
      amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaqueem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-two" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab-two">Label Two</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-three" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab-three">Label Three</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="half">
  <p>Open <strong>one</strong></p>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-four" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `max-height` to height but your `transition` effect will be dead. because in css you have to pass a `height` value to get transition effect.

I posted editable answer with `height:auto` and `opacity`

```css
.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  background: #16a085;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.blue label {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.tab-content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.tab-content p {
  margin: 1em;
}


/* :checked */

input:checked~.tab-content {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Icon */

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-one" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab-one">Label One</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.em ipsum dolor sit
      amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaqueem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur,
      architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.em ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo
      perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaqueem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum,
      maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-two" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab-two">Label Two</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-three" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab-three">Label Three</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="half">
  <p>Open <strong>one</strong></p>
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-four" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, architecto, explicabo perferendis nostrum, maxime impedit atque odit sunt pariatur illo obcaecati soluta molestias iure facere dolorum adipisci eum? Saepe, itaque.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```